# Valid MySQL query not returning result

Tags: php, mysql, datediff

I have a query in MySQL (thanks to user [Ross Smith II](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1432614/ross-smith-ii)) that I have tested in console, (returned 1 days 10 hours 34 minutes a few hours ago)  I am relatively sure my PHP is correct to, although it's possible I'm overlooking something, or there is a condition somewhere with this query that I just cannot do what I'm trying to do.  Would really appreciate some insight.  Please note the timestamp at the top will be a variable selected from another table, but for the purpose of this query I've put a time in the same format.  I've taken out all variables and tried raw data, still works in SQL query, but I cannot get the PHP to echo it.  I am receiving Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object.  Thanks again.

```
$aquery = ("SET @start = \"2013-01-19 07:56:22\";
        SET @end = NOW();

        SELECT
        CONCAT(
            FLOOR(
                (
                    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@start) - 86400 * (
                        (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(@end, @start) / 7) * 2) +
                            IF(WEEKDAY(@end) > 4, WEEKDAY(@end) - 4, 0) +
                            IF(WEEKDAY(@end) < WEEKDAY(@start), 2, 0)
                    )
                ) / 86400
            ),
            ' days ',
            TIME_FORMAT(
            SEC_TO_TIME(
                (
                    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@start) - 86400 * (
                        (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(@end, @start) / 7) * 2) +
                            IF(WEEKDAY(@end) > 4, WEEKDAY(@end) - 4, 0) +
                            IF(WEEKDAY(@end) < WEEKDAY(@start), 2, 0)
                    )
                ) % 86400
            ),
            '%H hours %i minutes'
            )
        ) AS duration");
        $aresult = $mysqli->query($aquery);
        // while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        // Edited typo above, does not fix.
        while ( $row = $aresult->fetch_assoc() ) {
        echo ($row['duration']);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call *query* with multiple queries like that. Query each of them individually (and remove the ;'s) or use [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

```
$aresult = $mysqli->multi_query($aquery);
```

or

```
$mysqli->query("SET @start = \"2013-01-19 07:56:22\"");
$mysqli->query("SET @end = NOW()");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT
    CONCAT(
        FLOOR(
            (
                UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@start) - 86400 * (
                    (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(@end, @start) / 7) * 2) +
                        IF(WEEKDAY(@end) > 4, WEEKDAY(@end) - 4, 0) +
                        IF(WEEKDAY(@end) < WEEKDAY(@start), 2, 0)
                )
            ) / 86400
        ),
        ' days ',
        TIME_FORMAT(
        SEC_TO_TIME(
            (
                UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@start) - 86400 * (
                    (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(@end, @start) / 7) * 2) +
                        IF(WEEKDAY(@end) > 4, WEEKDAY(@end) - 4, 0) +
                        IF(WEEKDAY(@end) < WEEKDAY(@start), 2, 0)
                )
            ) % 86400
        ),
        '%H hours %i minutes'
        )
    ) AS duration");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$aresult = $mysqli->query($aquery);
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        echo ($row['duration']);
}
```

This looks like a typo. Shouldn't you be using `$aresult->fetch_assoc()`?

Comment: Yes it was a typo, I have edited my original post as it did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple queries, which you can not execute diretly like the way you're trying. I'm using PDO so I'm not positive if this will do what you want. But give it a shot.

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
$mysqli->query("SET @start = '2013-01-19 07:56:22'");
$mysqli->query("SET @end = NOW()");
/*$aresult = */$mysqli->query("SELECT
    CONCAT(
        FLOOR(
            (
                UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@start) - 86400 * (
                    (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(@end, @start) / 7) * 2) +
                        IF(WEEKDAY(@end) > 4, WEEKDAY(@end) - 4, 0) +
                        IF(WEEKDAY(@end) < WEEKDAY(@start), 2, 0)
                )
            ) / 86400
        ),
        ' days ',
        TIME_FORMAT(
        SEC_TO_TIME(
            (
                UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@start) - 86400 * (
                    (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(@end, @start) / 7) * 2) +
                        IF(WEEKDAY(@end) > 4, WEEKDAY(@end) - 4, 0) +
                        IF(WEEKDAY(@end) < WEEKDAY(@start), 2, 0)
                )
            ) % 86400
        ),
        '%H hours %i minutes'
        )
    ) AS duration");
$mysqli->commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

After researching the mysqli_multi_query and taking into account [inhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/913097/inhan) and [ring0's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338904/ring0) answers, and thanks to [Ross Smith II](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1432614/ross-smith-ii), here is the solution I have come up with.  If anyone needs a PHP script to calculate elapsed time from a timestamp ($timeApproved here) and the current time (could be replaced with any other timestamp, replace @end = NOW() with your timestamp...) here it is.
It will return the amount of time in 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes format.
Thanks so much for the help.

**HERE IS THE UPDATED CODE**

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
$query = "SET @start = \"".$timeApproved."\";"; 
$query .= "SET @end = NOW();";
$query .= "SELECT
CONCAT(
    FLOOR(
        (
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@start) - 86400 * (
                (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(@end, @start) / 7) * 2) +
                    IF(WEEKDAY(@end) > 4, WEEKDAY(@end) - 4, 0) +
                    IF(WEEKDAY(@end) < WEEKDAY(@start), 2, 0)
            )
        ) / 86400
    ),
    ' days ',
    TIME_FORMAT(
    SEC_TO_TIME(
        (
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@start) - 86400 * (
                (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(@end, @start) / 7) * 2) +
                    IF(WEEKDAY(@end) > 4, WEEKDAY(@end) - 4, 0) +
                    IF(WEEKDAY(@end) < WEEKDAY(@start), 2, 0)
            )
        ) % 86400
    ),
    '%H hours %i minutes'
    )
) AS duration;"; 

if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)) {
do {

if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 

{
echo $row['duration'];
}

// mysqli_free_result($result); // I will only have one result.
}   
} while (mysqli_next_result($link));
}
```